# Multiple variable assignments in one row

Tags: javascript

As each programming language is different and my experience with Javascript is on basic level, I would like to know, how multiple variable assignments in one row are evaluated

Example:

```
 a = b = c = d = 5;
```

Will such statement assign `5` to each of 4 variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I'm surprised you have not simply tried it.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - It does, but I would like to have that confirmed from experienced users. From one case I cannot make a rule. I would like to learn it generally, if that would work always, or there are some hidden issues... Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QNzY7/

Comment: @Daedalus - I did - see comment above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer is *yes*, that statement will assign `5` to each of 4 variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. But, contrary to what was said, doesn't assign `5` to `d`, and then the value of `d` to `c`, but it will assign the same value to each variables, starting from the right-hand side. To be more clear, your statement:

```
var a, b, c, d;
a = b = c = d = 5;
```

It's equivalent to:

```
var d = 5;
var c = 5;
var b = 5;
var a = 5;
```

**Not** to:

```
var d = 5;
var c = d;
var b = c;
var a = b;
```

It's a subtle but important difference: in the first case, JavaScript just *sets* a value to all the variables. In the second case, JavaScript *set* a value to all the variables **but** also *get* the value of three variables (the value of `a` is not assigned anywhere).

A simple code that will show that:

```
// `this` is the global object if you run this code in the global scope.
// In the browsers the global object is `window`.
Object.defineProperties(this, {  
  "a": {  
    get: function() {
        console.log("get a");
    },
    set: function(value) {
        console.log("set a");
    }
  },  
  "b": {  
    get: function() {
        console.log("get b");
    },
    set: function(value) {
        console.log("set b");
    }
  },  
  "c": {  
    get: function() {
        console.log("get c");
    },
    set: function(value) {
        console.log("set c");
    }
  },  
  "d": {  
    get: function() {
        console.log("get d");
    },
    set: function(value) {
        console.log("set d");
    }
  }  
});

b = c = d = 5;
a = b;
```

On the console you should have:

```
set d
set c
set b
get b
set a
```

As you can see for the statement `b = c = d = 5` JS only *set* the variable, and call both `set` and `get` on `b`, because the statement `a = b`.

This distinction is very important, because if you define some getter for your property and you're not aware of this behavior, you will end up with unexpected bug using multiple variable assignments.

Comment: it's worth noting that the assignment expression returns the right value along with setting the left reference according to [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) says exactly the same thing in fact; I just tried to elaborate with an example that shows the set / get behavior, compare to previous answers.

Answer (score 5):

For the most part yes, but consider the following scenario:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, "b", { value : 6, writable : false });
var a, c, d;

a = b = c = d = 5;

console.log(a); // 5
console.log(b); // 6
console.log(c); // 5
console.log(d); // 5
```

Comment: Thanks. As expected - there is always some exception :)

Comment: good example of exception, and that's because the assignment `b = c` has a return value as 5 which is then assigned to `a`, but `b` is not writable actually (thus 6).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

```
a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=4; // all get to be 4
a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h={ p1:"1", p2:"2" }; // same object for all

a.p3 = "3";
console.log((a==b && b==c && c==d && d==e), f); // condition is true, f is now 
//    {
//        p1:"1",
//        p2:"2",
//        p3:"3"
//    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only to try it to know the answer: **Yes**.

The reason it works like that is that assignment takes whatever is on the right-hand side of the equals sign and assigns that value to the variable on the left-hand side.

So `5` is assigned to `d`; then the value of `d` is assigned to `c` and so on.

Comment: No, it is NOT assigned from right to left (`5` to `d`, `d` to `c`, and so on), but directly `5` to each one! See https://jsfiddle.net/rsja8ob3/ as a proof (Thanks @jalbee)

Comment: Interestingly, that is not necessarily true -- if you checkout the [Ecmascript Language Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), the assignment operator actually returns the right-side value, not the left-side variable. This would allow for right-to-left assignment, even in that special case scenario.