# Javascript order of execution of assignment expressions

Tags: javascript

the results why x=5,y=4
x=y+(y=x)*0
this line
x=5+(4)*0
why not?
x=4+(4)*0

```
var x=4; 
var y=5; 
x=y+(y=x)*0; 
console.log(x); 
console.log(y);
```

run on chrome console

Comment: See also [why the program's result is undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21979221/1048572) and [Javascript order of referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18495913/1048572). `y` is overwritten *after* it is read.

Answer (score 2):

Because `y=x` does not magically run before the rest of the line. JavaScript executes each bit in the expression as it comes; `y` comes first, and it is `5`; then `y = x` comes, and it is `4`.