# Javascript multiple variables x = y = z?

Tags: javascript, variables

I stumbled upon some examples of code and what I doesn't know is this `x = y = z;`

What does this code do?

Is this some kind of validation in javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple variable assignments in one row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514401/multiple-variable-assignments-in-one-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sets every variable to the value of the right-most expression. In this case, `x` and `y` will both get the value of `z`.

It's an easy way to instantiate multiple variables, for example

```
for (var i = j = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

will give you a loop with 2 counters initialised - one that auto increments, and one that you can manually handle inside the loop.

Comment: I thought about it and the answer makes sense, but hey this is javascript nothing can suprise me, thanks for answer bro, cheers

Comment: Fantastic link! hahah

Answer (score 0):

No, it simply means "Set x and y to z".

Answer (score 0):

No nothing like validation 
its simply assign value of    z to y and y to x.
so result is value of x , y and z are same.