# Two assignments in one line

Tags: javascript, var

Let's say we start with this:

`var foo = {n:1};
var bar = foo;`

In JavaScript, what is the order in which the following assignments are carried out:

`foo.x = foo = {n:2};`

When I looked up answers to this I found several that seemed to suggest that assignments happen from RIGHT TO LEFT, eg:

`foo = {n:2};
foo.x = foo;`

In which case we would expect:

`console.log(foo) //{n:2, x:Object} - (a circular reference back to foo)`

However what I see in the console when I actually do this suggests that assignments actually happen from LEFT TO RIGHT:

`console.log(foo) //{n:2}
console.log(bar) //{n:1, x:Object}` 
--> The {n:1} obj gets an 'x' property, and foo gets reassigned to a new object {n:2}

Can someone clarify for me the order of operations when there are multiple assignments in one line?

Also, what is the underlying rule that distinguishes the above scenario from a situation like the following:
[Multiple variable assignments in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514401/multiple-variable-assignments-in-one-row)

Some of the answers in the above question claim that assignments of primitives are carried out RIGHT TO LEFT...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The assignment does go from right to left. It's just that the resolution of `foo.x` happens before the assignment. ([Ecma Standard 11.13.1 Simple Assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1))

Think of it like this. Before the assignment, `foo` and `bar` happen to be pointing to the same object in memory. (We'll call it `inMemoryObject`).

```
foo --|
bar --|
      |---> inMemoryObject { 
                               n:1 
                           }
```

We then refer to `foo.x` at the beginning of an assignment method. Because `foo.x` doesn't exist, the placeholder gets created, ready to be assigned to.

```
foo --|
bar --|
      |---> inMemoryObject { 
                               n:1, 
                               x: undefined 
                           }
```

Once the variable is created, then the right-to-left assignment process begins, assigning to `inMemoryObject.x`. At the end of the assignment process, `foo` no longer points to `inMemoryObject`, but `bar` still does.

```
bar --|
      |---> inMemoryObject { 
                              n:1, 
                              x: --| 
foo --|                     }      |
      |                            |
      |----------------------------|--- secondInMemoryObject {
                                                                n:2
                                                             }
```

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: There is absolutely no such thing as "placeholder" objects.

Comment: Re-reading your answer and the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1), I've noticed why you did this together with a fatal flaw in my own answer. There's no "placeholder object", but instead, a *reference* to the property `x` of the in-memory object.

Comment: And by reference, I mean: http://es5.github.io/#x8.7 -- see the second paragraph, may be useful for your answer.

Comment: @gotnull The standard declares that the left-hand expression gets evaluated first: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1

Comment: @AndrewShepherd well explained, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The assignments happen from right to left, but the assignment target evaluation happens from left to right.

Basically the whole expression starts evaluating from left to right, but the actual assignment needs the return value from the right side. So the assigment itself has to happen after retuning the value of the evaluation of the right side.

Comment: "but the assignment target evaluation happens from left to right." -- the way you use "evaluation" is misleading. If the assignment targets were evaluated left-to-right then this would log `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/w8cbhdub/