# JavaScript Cross-File Private State in module

Tags: javascript, module

I am reading an article [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html), and wondering what does this snippet of code mean? Especially what does this kind of assignment do `var _private = my._private = my._private || {}`?

```
var MODULE = (function (my) {
    var _private = my._private = my._private || {},
        _seal = my._seal = my._seal || function () {
            delete my._private;
            delete my._seal;
            delete my._unseal;
        },
        _unseal = my._unseal = my._unseal || function () {
            my._private = _private;
            my._seal = _seal;
            my._unseal = _unseal;
        };

    // permanent access to _private, _seal, and _unseal

    return my;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to break it down.

```
var _private = my._private = my._private || {}?
```

You have two parts.

The first one is:

```
my._private = my._private || {}?
```

Which is [covered by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439579/what-does-var-foo-foo-mean-in-javascript).

The `||` operator resolves to the left hand side if the left hand side is true and the right hand side otherwise.

The second one is:

```
var _private = my._private = something
```

Which is [covered by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514401/multiple-variable-assignments-in-one-row).

The value of `something` is assigned to `my._private` and then that new value of `my._private` is assigned to `_private`, which is a locally scoped variable because [it has `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it).